# iOS Storyboarding App-Wide Elements (persitent Sidebar)

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard

I am learning iOS 6 Development and the first iPad app i want to build looks like this.

[image: iOS App]

I would like to know how to use the Storyboard to layout my Scenes, where the Sidebar (TableView) is always there. Only the area where the Map is should change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag a container view from the object explorer in to your view in storyboard. I will automatically add new scene with view controller. Change that to you tableview controller and you should be good to go. It wont work in ios5